# Web application configuration file

Tags: javascript, jquery, configuration, web-config, configuration-files

I am building a web app for my company and I need to get some info through a configuration file. 
I never did this before and I want to figure out the common way to do so. 
I'm only using JavaScript and jquery, no php. Which configuration file should I create? How can I read from it? How can the user update it?

Can you please help me understand which is the best way to do so in my case? 
Thank you for your help! 
Moran

Answer (score 0):

configuration files are extended with ext **.conf**. You can write your configuration details into it and then use it via **Ajax calls**.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I can't find one in the web. What kind of content does a .conf file have? How do I get it through ajax - same as json content?